# After 2nd log in to AAD, subsequent attempts fail

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I used below code to login to my Paid Acct in AzureAD with Xamarin Forms. I have set permission: `internet and access network state` and the 1st and 2nd attempts to log in were okay.

The subsequent attempts to log in got *stuck* at "Take you to your organization sign-in page".This means there is no result returned and the activity indicator kept running indefinitely.

Why cannot log in again? Why can I log in the 1st and 2nd attempts? I have used the correct parameters.

```
public interface IAuthenticationService {
    Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority,
        string resource, string clientId, string returnUri);
}

private async void Login_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    var authenticationService = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticationService>();

    try {
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationService.Authenticate(
            AuthenticationParameters.Authority,
            AuthenticationParameters.GraphResourceUri,
            AuthenticationParameters.ApplicationId,
            AuthenticationParameters.ReturnUri);

        if (authenticationResult != null) {
            var strToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            await DisplayAlert("Success", strToken, "Ok");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        string strErr = ex.ToString();
        await DisplayAlert("Failure", "Authentication failed.", "Ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to run this within an emulator and capture the traffic with Fiddler. Most likely there _is_ an error getting returned that the auth lib isn't processing properly.

Comment: @Marc I am using Droid phone for testing on Company AD in Azure AD. I don't know how to configure  emulator as emulator in VS2017 for Windows is very slow. I don't know what I can do with the ADAL if there is error.

Comment: How emulator call the AzureAD and my ADFS? How to configure this? I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: You need to use an emulator so you can capture the traffic going down the wire (Fiddler runs on Windows, not Android). I don't know of a mechanism for capturing network traffic on Android directly (although I imagine there must be something out there). Without seeing the traffic, it will be very difficult to debug what is going on.