# What to use to check Expiry in JWT

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

newbie in JWT and AzureAD. Say, I received the JWT from Azure as below:

Problem:

1) WHAT To use to handle this JWT

2) How to access the exp in JWT.

3) what this number 1516890687 means and How to handle it

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/",
  "iat": 1516886787,
  "nbf": 1516886787,
  "exp": 1516890687,
  "aio": "Y2NgYEjJXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=",
  "app_displayname": "XXXXXXXX",
  "appid": "xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,

   ....

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the libraries you use do that for you.For example [adal](https://github.com/rcervantes/xamarin-adal) or [msal](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2). Using any of those you have full access to the values in the token

Comment: This is pretty clearly spelled out in the JWT [RFC 7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519) and on reference sites like jwt.io.  Since it's a standard claim, most libraries will validate it for you as well.

Comment: @astaykov, I am having problem to use adal. There are issues with adal and no one can help me. I am putting up this issue here to help other who may have same problem. example: do you know that Adal has problem? The 1st and 2nd login is OK, subsequent login will be in a loop. Here the link I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426491/after-2nd-log-in-to-aad-subsequent-attempts-fail

Comment: I am new to AzureAD and JWT. There are terms not clear. I need help as Refresh token is another huge topic. So, I thought check expiry will help me to understand what I can do in certain scenarios. please help. Thanks

Comment: @astaykov, the adal sample in your link not working. Error msg:Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete ---> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)
2. Using MSAL it is quite easy: `authenticationResult.ExpiresOn`
3. Using MSAL you will not have to handle it manually. Otherwise it is a unix timestamp, so `1516890687` is `01/25/2018 @ 2:31pm (UTC)`.

Comment: Yeah, and you should not look inside the JWTs anyway unless you really need it (and you don't in this case, since the authentication result contains the info), the task of validating the access token is for the API, not the client.

Comment: Also, MSAL is for the v2 endpoint. If you use v1, use ADAL instead.

Comment: @Evz, I am using ADAL.  How to handle this time 1516890687. Is this milliseconds? How I know when it is expiring ? How to handle the JWT which is in Json format? I have no experience on this. Your help is very much needed. Thanks

Comment: Why are using ADAL? Do you have a special need in it? MSAL is newer and recommended for use by MS. Regarding the time value I already explained what it is in my answer. You should not care when it expires, the API should. You should not handle JWT as json yourself, use - MSAL or ADAL for that.

Comment: @EvZ, my company is using Azure AD and not AzureAD B2C.  We only allow company staff to use. Can I use MSAL even not for Azure B2C. Is MSAL provide the same functionality for ADAL. I have other requirements. I need to know the expiry because the phone will be used in offline mode for many hours.